# How to get client_addr in Falcon Request object ?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, falconframework, falcon

There is **remote_addr** and **access_routes** in falcon Request object, but what is needed is [client_addr](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.client_addr) of the request what is there in Pyramid 
I am not getting it how this can be done. without checking headers and all info.

Comment: `req.remote_addr` is what you need?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I added the answer. remote_addr is correct but that is not absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, to get exact client_address, we should first check **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR** header and if after splitting by comma i.e. HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR.split(",")[0] is present than that is the client address otherwise **request.remote_addr** is the client address. This is needed especially in the case of Load balancer in front of your service and this is how **Pyramid** calculated **client_addr**.